# Fair Allocation to Buckets with Constraints

Tags: optimization, constraints, allocation

I have a vector with n prices(p1,p2,...,pn).

I want to allocate these into 3 buckets A,B,C such that the average of all the prices in each bucket is as close as possible. The constraint will be that each basket has a different number of prices put into it.

Using R I've tried to MIN the squared difference between the prices in each bucket, but I'm not getting the correct results.

Am I approaching this correctly?

So the way I approached it was I had a vector:

```
x<-c(50,50,50,10,20,40,50,20,4,40,20)
```

And I want to Minimise

```
A<-|(0x[0]+1x[1]+0x[2]+0x[3]....)  - allocation * average price |^2
B<-|(0x[0]+1x[1]+0x[2]+0x[3]....)   - allocation * average price |^2
C<-|(0x[0]+1x[1]+0x[2]+0x[3]....)   - allocation * average price |^2
```

To get the square differences from the average

Such that each bucket is either allocated or not allocated that specific price.

The constraints would be the allocations of A, B, C would be say 10 to A 5 to B and 12 to C.

Comment: You probably need a binary variable `x(i,j)` indicating if price `i` is allocated to bucket `j`. I am not sure what you exactly mean by `each basket has a different number of prices put into it` but may be you mean each price `i` can only go into a single bucket `j`. That can be modeled with a simple linear inequality, 

Binary variables mean you need a MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) solver. If you insist on a quadratic objective this becomes a MIQP. Of course one also could use an objective based on a linear deviation.

Comment: I do mean each price `i` can only go into single bucket `j`. What would the objective function be?

Comment: E.g. `min maxavgprice - minavgprice` `minavgprice` and `maxavgprice` are easy once you have `avgprice(i)` of each bucket. The calculation of `avgprice(j)` is nonlinear but can be linearized..

Comment: I didn't realise it was possible to `linearize avgprice(j)`. How do you do that?

Comment: It is based on linearizing a multiplication of  a binary variable with a continuous variable. There are standard formulations for this.

Comment: See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/05/linearizing-average.html) for a more detailed  explanation how to linearize this.